# pugjs - radio button checked attribute as variable

Tags: mixins, pugjs

Working on a pugjs mixin.  Creating radio buttons in a loop over json. Normal name-value pairs are work as expected.  In the loop, setting a radio button to checked by default is fine.  Trying to figure out how to **not set** the checked value for non-selected radio buttons.

I can do this with javascript but seems like I should be able to do this in pug.

Tried setting a variable

```
-checked =(!fVar.checked)?'checked':''
```

and then use in tag

```
input(type='radio' #{checked})
```

Is there a way to do this in pug?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out one way.  Not as direct as I would like but I nested mixins. 
The main mixin has a case statement that calls child mixins.

```
case fVar.checked
            when 'true'
                +radioChecked()
            when 'false'
                +radioUnchecked()
```

Not very D.R.Y. but it works.